# Android apply different Text Selection Handles

Tags: android

I've created the bellow style to change the selection handles on an `EditText`.

```
  <style name="AutoCompleteTextViewOrangeAutoComplete" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.AutoCompleteTextView">
      <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/orangeautocomplete_list_selector_holo_light</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/orangeautocomplete_edit_text_holo_light</item>
        <item name="android:textSelectHandle">@drawable/orangehandle_text_select_handle_middle</item>
        <item name="android:textSelectHandleLeft">@drawable/orangehandle_text_select_handle_left</item>
        <item name="android:textSelectHandleRight">@drawable/orangehandle_text_select_handle_right</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHighlight">#99db4b39</item>
  </style>
```

On my layouts, some of my `TextViews` can be selected so I want to apply the same selection handles but since I have many `TextViews`I would like to apply the handles to all of my app.

On `AndroidManifest` I have this:

```
<activity
                        android:name=".Fragments"
                        android:exported="false"
                        android:label="@string/app_name"
                        android:theme="@style/myTheme">
```

And on `Values-v14` my `styles.xml` is like this:

```
<resources>

    <style name="myTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/test</item>
    </style>

    <style name="test" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.TextView">
        <item name="android:textSelectHandle">@drawable/orangehandle_text_select_handle_middle</item>
        <item name="android:textSelectHandleLeft">@drawable/orangehandle_text_select_handle_left</item>
        <item name="android:textSelectHandleRight">@drawable/orangehandle_text_select_handle_right</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHighlight">#99db4b39</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"/>
</resources>
```

Unfortunately this is not changing the default text selection handles.

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: I have a similar problem, and I'm using the AppCompat library too. Maybe that's the point. They use some different value to take the drawables from, or something like that. Are there other people with AppCompat who succeded in changing the text select handle? @Favolas, if you change something and it starts to work, please let me know.